# Splitting strings from pandas column into multiple strings

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am sorry if this question is already answered, but I did not find any. I want to split & convert long strings in multiple strings
I have dataframe df:

```
       no         strings
1.  A_12_234   gef|re1234|gef|re0943
2.  O_257363   tef|fe4545|tef|fe3333|tef|9995
```

I want to make individual strings and create new column

output I am getting:

```
       no         strings                          new_col
1.  A_12_234   gef|re1234|gef|re0943                <thekeys db="gef" value="re1234"/>\n<thekeys db="gef" value="re0943"/>

2.  O_257363   tef|fe4545|tef|fe3333|tef|9995       <thekeys db="tef" value="fe4545"/>\n<thekeys db="tef" value="fe3333"/>
```

Desired output:

```
         no         strings                          new_col
1.  A_12_234   gef|re1234|gef|re0943                <thekeys db="gef" value="re1234"/>\n<thekeys db="gef" value="re0943"/>

2.  O_257363   tef|fe4545|tef|fe3333|tef|9995       <thekeys db="tef" value="fe4545"/>\n<thekeys db="tef" value="fe3333"/>\n<thekeys db="tef" value="9995"/>
```

I dont know where I am making a mistake, since it is skipping some pairs

Here's code:

```
def createxm(x):
try:
    parsedlist = x['strings'].split('|')
    print(parsedlist)
    cnt = len(parsedlist)/2
    print(cnt)
    xm_list = []
    for i in range(0, int(cnt), 2):
        xm_list.append('<thekeys db="{}" value="{}"/>'.format(parsedlist[i], parsedlist[i+1]))
        xm_string = '\n'.join(xml_list)
    return xm_string
except:
    return None
```

Thank you

Comment: The output from your code and the desired output are the same. Can you please paste the correct desired output

Comment: @sharathnatraj hi, they are not same in my output one pair is missing

Comment: Got it. Sorry, I missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. The problem was in the place where you divide `cnt = len(parsedlist/2)`.

Corrected code:

```
def createxm(x):
    try:
        parsedlist = x['strings'].split('|')
        print(parsedlist)
        cnt = len(parsedlist)
        print(cnt)
        xm_list = []
        for i in range(0, int(cnt), 2):
            xm_list.append('<thekeys db="{}" value="{}"/>'.format(parsedlist[i], parsedlist[i+1]))
            xm_string = '\n'.join(xm_list)
        return xm_string
    except:
        return None
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x:createxm(x), axis=1)
```

Prints:

```
df.new_col.iloc[1]
'<thekeys db="tef" value="fe4545"/>\n<thekeys db="tef" value="fe3333"/>\n<thekeys db="tef" value="9995"/>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the values on `|` then use first four values to get the required string, you can use `str.format()`

```py
fString = '<thekeys db="{}" value="{}"/>\n<thekeys db={} value="{}"/>'
df['strings'].str.split('|').apply(lambda x: fString.format(x[0], x[1], x[2],  x[3]))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
1.0    <thekeys db="gef" value="re1234"/>\n<thekeys d...
2.0    <thekeys db="tef" value="fe4545"/>\n<thekeys d...
Name: strings, dtype: object
```